wanted all the 3rd party dependency list in my maven project. How can I do this?
Required to get all the 3rd party dependencies from my Maven project.
For my case I directed mvn dependency:tree and grepped all the text which was in '{}:{}:{}:{}' format to a text file. But I believe there should be a better way for this.

Does mvn dependency:list suffice?

Perhaps mvn dependency:list -DoutputFile=deps.txt would do what you want?
